# Why is there no prism region registred in my regionManager?

Tags: c#, prism

I am trying to setup my first prism application. I have a simple MainWindowShell with a contentControl with a prism regionName and a ViewA displayed in this region. Now i want to switch from ViewA to ViewB, but i have problems with the navigation. Everything seems to be perfectly wired up, but when it comes to regionManager.RequestNavigate(...) there is no region registred in the regionManager and the navigation fails. I think i have tracked the problem, but i can not solve it.

I am using a customControl. So there is no xaml. The xaml comes from a controlTemplate/styling in a resourceDictionary and this seems to be the problem.

I have tried the same with a userControl, copied the code from the controlTemplate and voila! there was my region perfectly registred in the regionManager. But i don't want to use userControls, because every viewElement is customized from a resourceDictionary by stylings and templates. So i would have a lot of empty useless "xyUserControl.xaml"s

I thought i could have found a solution - or at least a workaround - for my problem here on stackoverflow ([Prism Regions from Custom RegionAdapter Not Showing in RegionManager List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249284/prism-regions-from-custom-regionadapter-not-showing-in-regionmanager-list)). But i don't know how to do that in my case or if it's even possible. Because the solution would be to set the regionManager in the code behind like this:
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(targetContentControl, regionManager); But my code behind doesn't know anything from the xaml-template. So i desperately tried this: RegionManager.SetRegionManager(this, regionManager); ...didn't work. I am out of ideas.

Here is the RessourceDictionary:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type userControls:MainWindowShell}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MainWindowShell}" />
  </Style>

  <ControlTemplate x:Key="MainWindowShell" TargetType="{x:Type userControls:MainWindowShell}">
      <Grid>
      <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static utilities:RegionNames.Content}">
      </ContentControl>
      </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

And the MainWindowShell:

```
public class MainWindowShell : Window
{
    static MainWindowShell()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MainWindowShell), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MainWindowShell)));
    }

    public MainWindowShell(IMainMenuViewModel viewModel, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the region manually (from the constructor or elsewhere) is the way to go.

But you cannot just reference the `ContentControl` from its automagically created field, you have to look it up in the template with `GetTemplateChild` and its part-name.

I suspect that it may be a bit problematic for the *shell* (in fact any region-hosting control) as your control is expected to work with missing parts by convention. You should at least make a note to those creating the themes that the region-parts are mandatory. Also, add those `TemplatePart` attributes...

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I had to override OnApplyTemplate to call RegionManager.SetRegionManager there.